# jquery .not() not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have something happen on every instance except where there is a disabled class, but .not() doesn't seem to work. Here is a short version of what I have:

```
if($(this).not('.Disabled')){
     -Do Something-
}
```

However, if I reverse it, i.e.

```
if($(this).is('.Disabled')){
     -Do Something-
}
```

then the "is" will work on an element with the class of "Disabled"
Kind of confused where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assuming that `is` and `not` are opposites of each other. In fact, they aren't. `not()` will return a jQuery object, while `is` will return a boolean value indicating whether or not at least one item in the jQuery object it is executed against meets the selector you pass it.

The following should accomplish what you're attempting:

```
if(!$(this).is('.Disabled')){-Do Something- }
```

Answer (score 5):

The [`.not` method](http://api.jquery.com/not) returns a jQuery object containing the elements in this set that don't match the  selector.
It doesn't return a boolean.

In other words, it's the opposite of `.filter`, not `.is`.

You could write `if ($(this).not('.Disabled').length)` to check whether the jQuery object it creates is empty.

However, you should use the unary negation operator:  `if (!something)`

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) to test if an element has a class:

```
if($(this).hasClass("disabled")) {
    // i am disabled
}
```

If you're talking about the disabled *attribute*, then use the [`:disabled`](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) selector:

```
if($(this).is(":disabled")) {
    // i am disabled
}
```

Comment: I agree, this does seem nicer. However the .not() should be working as well, can't see what is wrong with it. +

Comment: I am looking for the opposite. Something like "doesn't have class".

Comment: @Tami `if(!$(this).hasClass("something")) {...`

Comment: @Lauw: `.not` doesn't return a boolean.

Comment: ...it returns an object. And and object is *always* truthy.

Comment: ah k thanks, didnt know that, was just looking at an example on jquery.com: 
    $("div").not(".green, #blueone")
            .css("border-color", "red");

appeared to do that, guess im missing something, thanks for clarifying things :)

Comment: Logic is inverted. OP wants to do something to each element that is _not_ disabled. Ignore comment. Posted too soon. Sorry.

Comment: Didn't know that you could used the bang (!). Will give that a go, as that seems to make the most sense.

Comment: I'm using if(!$(this).is('.Disabled')){

Comment: You know, I didn't even realise that worked :), and it does: http://jsfiddle.net/VYUfp/

Comment: I'm reading your code comment in the voice of Roy from the IT Crowd.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery not will return a list with the elements in the not parameter removed, so the if statement is actually just the size of that list. You should use:

```
$(this).not('.Disabled').each(function() {
// do something
});
```