# .not Selector is acting like a toggle?

Tags: jquery

### `.not` does not mean "not"?

First off, I know there are a lot of threads on the `.not` selector and I've tried several stack overflow solutions, but I haven't had any success so far.

In my current project, I'm adding and removing content visibility using jQuery. My issue though, when I click on a list-item twice, it toggles between being visible and hidden. I thought the `.not` selector would prevent this, but [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533675/jquery-not-not-working) left me with the impression that the `.not` selector is not necessarily what I think it is. I'm currently using

`$('.rokSprocket > div._' + num)`

to make the content visible, and

`$('.rokSprocket > div').not('._' + num)`

with the intent of making all other content inside my container invisible. If the `.not` doesn't necessarily mean "not this element/class/etc.", is there a  selector I can substitute in it's place?

**jQuery:**

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".nav-tabs > li").click(function () {
                    var $this = $(this),
                        classes = $this.attr('class').toString().split(/s+/),
                        num = 0;
                
                    $.each(classes, function (i, v) {
                        if (v.match(/_\d+/gim).length) num = v.split('_')[1];
                    });
                    
                    $('.rokSprocket > div._' + num)
                        .removeClass('hidden')
                        .addClass('visible');
                
                    $('.rokSprocket > div').not('._' + num)
                        .removeClass('visible')
                        .addClass('hidden');
                    
                    $('.nav-tabs > li._' + num)
                        .addClass('active');
                
                    $('.nav-tabs > li').not('._' + num)
                        .removeClass('active');
                });
            });
            </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="nav-tabs">
    <li class="_1 active">Painting</li>
    <li class="_2">Tile Floors</li>
    <!-- Etc -->
    <!-- Etc -->
    <!-- Etc -->
</ul>

<div class="rocSprocket">
    <div class="_1 visible painting">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>

    <div class="_2 hidden tileFloors">
        <p>Different Content</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Etc -->
    <!-- Etc -->
    <!-- Etc -->
</div>
```

**jsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/o39zgp04/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems

```
classes = $this.attr('class').toString().split(/\s+/),//need to use \s for space
```

then

```
if (v.match(/_\d+/gim)) num = v.split('_')[1];//match will return null if no match is found
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gycjcovx/)

---

But it can be simplified a lot like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-tabs > li").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      type = $this.data('id');

    $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $('.rokSprocket ._' + type).addClass('visible').removeClass('hidden').siblings('.visible').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 2%
}
.active {
  text-decoration: underline
}
.hidden {
  display: none
}
.visible {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-tabs">
  <li class="active" data-id="1">Painting</li>
  <li data-id="2">Tile Floors</li>
  <!-- Etc -->
  <!-- Etc -->
  <!-- Etc -->
</ul>

<div class="rokSprocket">
  <div class="_1 visible painting">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>

  <div class="_2 hidden tileFloors">
    <p>Different Content</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Etc -->
  <!-- Etc -->
  <!-- Etc -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for not only answering the question, but for providing the explanation! I GREATLY appreciate your help :)